# Clear All fields after Hit the Save button

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I  have working on forms, after i filled all the fields  and Click on Save button, all fields have been saved but the text fields was not empty, all entered text still present, How do removed those text after hit on the save button

Comment: Of course the data will still be there after saving, why wouldn't it? Is this a bound or unbound form?

Comment: I suspect you are quite new to access and may benefit from this resource: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCHt5Fz7cYrQIIw4EyXkkqPQ

Comment: thanks Harvey..currently i am using access 2007,i hope  2013 will help myself

Answer (score 6):

Go to a new record:

```
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
```

Answer (score 3):

May be you would like to add the following in the click on save button event before "End Sub"

```
Me.TextboxName.Value = Null
```

Comment: thanks Emi..it works for all fields for me except on Date of Birth fields i got an error...

Comment: my Date of Birth look like this 'Me.DOB.Value = "" which same to all fields but when i save the form it pointing to this fields as an error. the error shown as **Run time errror 3314: You must enter a value in the tblename.DOB fields**

Comment: Is the field's required property set to true? And where are you writing the code Me.DOB.Value = Null? Write it after your code for saving the values in the text boxes to the table.

Answer (score 3):

Try this routine linked to a button you want to click to clear all textboxes in an unbound form:

```
Private Sub CleanAllFieldsButton_Click()
Dim ctl As Control
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If ctl.ControlType = acTextBox Then ctl = Null
Next
Set ctl = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Private Sub Command47_Click()
On Error Resume Next
Me.Dirty = False 'Attempt to save the record
If Err.Number = 0 Then
'Only enter a new record, leaving other newly-added record accessible
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
Else MsgBox Err.DESCRIPTION, vbCritical, "Error"
End If
End Sub
```

Try this is in your save records click event.