# A command button that save data and clear fields after saving

Tags: ms-access

I am new in Access and I want to know how can I save data and then clear the fields from the data.
I used some vb commands to make the text null but I have an AutomateNumber that can't be regenerate.
So, how can I regenerate that AutomateNumber with a vb command or is there another way to clear all fields from all kinds of data?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32987928/clear-all-fields-after-hit-the-save-button  --- For Clear Data

Comment: I read it but I couldn't find what I asked here @RïshïKêshKümar

Comment: okk .. I try to solve your Problem .. give me some time ..

Comment: can you add Your Code Here ... if You Can ....

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar Thank you very much!

Comment: Private Sub command6_Click()
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSave
Me.Text15 = Null // this is the AutoNumber text
[Text22].Value = ""
[Text24].Value = ""
[Text26].Value = ""
[Text28].Value = ""
[Text30].Value = ""


End Sub
@RïshïKêshKümar

Comment: TextboxName.Value = Null

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clear All fields after Hit the Save button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32987928/clear-all-fields-after-hit-the-save-button)

Answer (score 1):

As your form seems to be bound, all you need is:

```
Private Sub command6_Click()
    DoCmd.GoToRecord, , acNewRec
End Sub
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32987928/clear-all-fields-after-hit-the-save-button  --- Its' U :)

Comment: Yes, you are right, forgot all about it. So this is really a duplicate question.

Comment: Oh and last question if I want to make a button that only cleans the fields without saving them, I can use the command :Private Sub command6_Click()
acNewRec
End Sub                                                                                                      Or it's not possible? @Gustav

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar